# API_KEY is not used error in my inspector

Tags: reactjs

every time I used this parameter "**${}**"on vscode I always got an issue. can someone help me figure out the issue please.

I'm using the last vscode.

thanks

That's my code

```js
const API_KEY = "19f84e11932abbc79e6d83f82d6d1045";

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: '/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US',

  fetchNetflixOriginals: '/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}$with_networks=213',
  fetchTopRated: '/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US',
  fetchActionMovies: '/discover/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&with_genre=28',
  fetchComedyMovies: '/discover/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&with_genre=35',
  fetchHorrorMovies: '/discover/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&with_genre=27',
  fetchRomanceMovies: '/discover/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&with_genre=10749',
  fetchDocumentaries: '/discover/movie?api_key={API_KEY}&with_genre=99',
}
export default requests;
```

Comment: you need t o use backticks in order to use the variable in the template string ```const t = `test_${variable}` ```

Answer (score 0):

change this code below.

```
const API_KEY = "19f84e11932abbc79e6d83f82d6d1045";

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,

  fetchNetflixOriginals: `/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}$with_networks=213`,
  fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
  fetchActionMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=28`,
  fetchComedyMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=35`,
  fetchHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=27`,
  fetchRomanceMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=10749`,
  fetchDocumentaries: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genre=99`,
}
export default requests;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a template literal instead of a string:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Use string like this:

```
const requests = {
    fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
    fetchNetflixOriginals: `/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_networks=213`,
    fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
    fetchActionMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=28`,
    fetchComedyMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_generes=35`,
    fetchHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_generes=27`,
    fetchRomanceMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_generes=10749`,
    fetchDocumentaries: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_generes=99`,
}
```